Ungetc() Not Ungetting Character
My code is extremely simple, but I figure that's best to figure out what's going on in my program.  For some reason, I can't seem to get ungetc() to work properly, nor can I figure out it's purpose.  Normally, ungetc() should return a character back into the stream or, at least, I think it should.  For example, if I type ABC, getting three characters through getchar(), I would expect ungetc() to return one of the letters getchar() had returned.  If I later call putchar(), I would expect B to be returned, since C was tossed back into the stream, but C was returned.  I've tried both getchar() as well as getc() and run into the same issue.
Condensed version, I typed "ABC" into my program, expecting ungetc() to cause the putc() to return 'B', but all I get is C again.  Why is this happening?
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    c=getchar();
    c=getchar();
    c=getchar();
    ungetc(c, stdout);
    putchar(c);
}


ungetc is an INPUT function.  Use ungetc(c, stdin);.  BTW, all that does is put c back into the input buffer, so the next getchar will get that again.  It doesn't change c.

Thanks for the response, it was very helpful.  I tested ungetchar() by using it before each c=getchar() and it seems work.  If I don't use unget() char, it cycles through the input stream.  If I use unget() char after each getchar(), it stays on A, meaning A (or the first character) is going back on the buffer.
